# How to sumif with multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

My sheet looks like this:

```
1|A      | B
2|amount | source
3|173.00 | bank1
4|173.00 | cc
5|173.00 | cash
6|173.00 | bank2
7|173.00 | cc
8|SUM
```

This is simplified but what I want to do is Sumif A3:A7 if B3:B7 does not contain cash or cc. Sumif needs to either include or exclude 2 criterion.

My working solution is

```
=(sumif(B3:B7,"<>cc",A3:A7)-sumif(B3:B7,"cash",A3:A7))
```

Just wanted to know if anyone knew a way to exclude/include more than one criteria in a straight-forward way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumproduct($A$3:$A$7,$B$3:$B$7<>"cc",$B$3:$B$7<>"cash"))
```

This is a way for you to apply two different evaluations of cell contents (cc and cash) to the same range of numbers.

Comment: This is such a powerful formula. Opens up a whole new world of possibilities... Helped me solve a problem that took me about 1 hour. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

This is also a possible solution for this specific question:

```
=(sumif(B3:B7,"bank*",A3:A7))
```

but the first answer is more flexible.

Comment: Best to use the simplest solution when possible! Spreadsheet formulas can get out of hand really quickly, especially array formulas.