# How do I add isblank(ref) criteria to arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets

This is an improvement of work from [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36014/how-to-sumif-with-multiple-criteria).

I have an array formula that is similar to this image:

[image: Google Spreadsheet Image with formula]

It sums column A when the date in F matches the due date (C). What I want to do is only sum A when F matches C and B is blank. This way when I add a date into the "Paid On" Column, G and H will no longer reflect that payment as "needed".

This would make my budget sheet much better.

Comment: The link to the doc doesn't work- says "That is not a valid spreadsheet URL."

Comment: so, when you say "When F matches C" do you mean in the same row? Or do you mean when C's value is found in F?

Comment: I've added an IF THEN ELSE to the query formula. See `playground` sheet.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Added comments to spreadsheet to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a new sheet in the spreadsheet your working in, called "playground". There I started playing around and ended up with a `QUERY` formula. First I reproduced your result:

`=QUERY(A:D;"SELECT C, SUM(A) GROUP BY C PIVOT D")` **(See F2)**

Secondly I added your request:

`=QUERY(A:D;"SELECT C, SUM(A) WHERE B IS NULL GROUP BY C PIVOT D")` **(See I2)**

**UPDATE**
If you start adding rows, the result is getting odd; an extra blank row and column is added. I had to re-arrange the query a bit to adjust for that:

`=QUERY(A:D;"SELECT C, SUM(A)  WHERE (D IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL AND A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NULL) GROUP BY C PIVOT D")`

**UPDATE 12-02-2013**
To complete the answering, I've updated the result with the following query:
`=QUERY(A:B;"SELECT SUM(A) WHERE(B IS NOT NULL) LABEL SUM(A) 'Total Amount Due'")`

The `QUERY` function is extremely powerful and with a bit of `SQL` knowledge easy to use !!

See references for help (or asks again):

- [QUERY](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882)
- [Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Introduction)

Comment: This is really good. It almost does what I want. There are some odd things about it. The biggest problem is that all totals disappear when B3:B is blank. I like the way it eliminates dates where nothing is due.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

I think this will help:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$8<>"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH($C$2:$C$8,$F$2:$F$11,0)),false,true),$A$2:$A$8))
```

Comment: You're missing out on due dates 8,9,10. The result of your query yields only one value?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, good point. Thanks for letting me know. I have fixed the error.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra, About returning one value, yes, that was my intention. I thought the OP's requested to do a sum based on his conditions, which I thought he meant to return the sum only, not the rows that match. BTW, +1 to your answer. I had no clue Google Spreadsheets could do queries like that

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. 
@JacobJanTuinstra - I never realized how easy it was to add SQL code in excel. Thanks for this.
@joseph4tw - your answer worked great for a single value.

See my live preview for the solution.

```
=arrayformula(sumif(C2:C8 & D2:D8 & B2:B8,F2:F11 & G1 & "",A2:A8))
```

It was so easy I don't know why I didn't try it before.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, you basically want to have the sum of the due amount based on payment dates: `=SUM(FILTER(A3:A9;B3:B9<>""))`. I don't see how this can be influenced by the other logic you're adding... It's more efficient to add this type of information to the question.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. I want to know how much need to be in each account on each day. As payments post I want to add the date and have the action of adding that date cause the amount due to be removed from the list.

Comment: Have a look at the `playground` sheet. Is this what you want? I'm close to down voting your answer btw.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I want and is better than my solution in every way except that All amounts should show when no dates are entered. Currently no amounts show if I remove all text from column B.