# How to aggregate two OR criteria in same sumif

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

The formula below is the same other than the last criteria: in the first it should equal "IN BETWEEN" and in the second it should equal "BUSY".

```
=SUMIFS('2016/09/26'!$S$3:$S,'2016/09/26'!$A$3:$A,H3,'2016/09/26'!$C$3:$C,"IN BETWEEN")+
SUMIFS('2016/09/26'!$S$3:$S,'2016/09/26'!$A$3:$A,H3,'2016/09/26'!$C$3:$C,"BUSY")
```

I wanted to aggregate both in the same formula with something like an OR condition but couldn't get it to work as I don't know the syntax. What I tried throws a "Formula Parse" error:

```
=SUMIFS('2016/09/26'!$S$3:$S,'2016/09/26'!$A$3:$A,A3,'2016/09/26'!$C$3:$C,
OR(="IN BETWEEN",="BUSY"))
```

Comment: Is this useful? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36014/354

Answer (score 1):

The right way to write OR arguments is `OR(A1="string1",A1="string2")` but OR doesn't allow arrays as arguments.

As [Aʟ E.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/a%CA%9F-e) pointed out, there is [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36014/354) related to the core or the question on this site about that is specific for AND conditions and this question is about a combination of AND and OR conditions.

One alternative is to take advantage that boolean values, TRUE and FALSE are interpreted as 1 and 0 respectively when arithmetic operations are applied to them.

- A multiplication of TRUE/FALSE is equivalent to AND.
- A sum of TRUE/FALSE of mutually excluded comparisons is directly equivalent to OR.

See the following pattern

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A6,(B1:B6="A")*((C1:C6="B")+(C1:C6="C")))
```

Just replace the ranges an values with those of your specific problem. The result is the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('2016/09/26'!$S$3:$S,
('2016/09/26'!$A$3:$A=H3)*
(('2016/09/26'!$C$3:$C="IN BETWEEN")+('2016/09/26'!$C$3:$C="BUSY"))
)
```

## See also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238816/using-sumifs-with-multiple-and-or-conditions